# Whether to use "par" or "à" in the "make someone do something" construction

Tags: prépositions, constructions-causatives

> J'ai **fait examiner** les feuilles en question **par** des amis de la police scientifique.

This is the first time I’ve seen the preposition "par" used instead of "à" in the construction "make someone do something" or "have something done by someone". How does using "par" differ in meaning from using "à"?

> J'ai **fait examiner** les feuilles en question **à** des amis de la police scientifique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles et corrects. Si souvent on emploie l'un ou l'autre sans y réfléchir on peut cependant par le choix de *à* ou de *par* vouloir exprimer une différence.

> J'ai fait examiner les feuilles en question à des amis de la police scientifique.

→  L'important c'est que les feuilles aient été examinées, au passage j'informe que ça a été fait par des amis de la police scientifique.

> J'ai fait examiner les feuilles en question par des amis de la police scientifique.

→  Indique que j'avais le choix entre plusieurs personnes pour faire examiner ces feuilles, j'ai choisi mes amis de la police scientifique et pas quelqu'un d'autre.

Peut-être que l'exemple suivant sera plus clair. Mon fils a reçu des amis et ils ont laissé un désordre incroyable dans la maison.

> Je vais faire faire le ménage à mon fils.

→ j'emploie *à* parce que mon intention est de lui faire payer son attitude (et celle de ses amis !), c'est en quelque sorte une punition.

> Je vais faire faire le ménage par la femme de ménage.

→ je laisse tout passer à mon fils, il fait ce qu'il veut et je peux payer quelqu'un pour réparer ses dégâts.

Comment: To: @Laure I wonder if sometimes it is obligatory to use "par"? "Faites lire ce livre à les enfants **par** Albert." Using "à" in this sentence sounds clumsy. "Faites lire ce livre à les enfants **à** Albert." Merci.

Comment: @L Faites lire ce livre **aux** enfants. Effectivement c'est un cas ou il faut employer « par » car on désigne  Albert (et pas quelqu'un d'autre) mais  je ne dirais pas (même si c'est correct) « Faites lire ce livre aux enfants par Albert » mais plutôt « Dites à Albert de lire ce livre aux enfants. »