# "Cervantes has Don Quixote say..."

Tags: constructions-causatives

Si je veux dire ça en français, j'ai, je crois, deux façons pour le dire :

> 1. Cervantès fait Don Quichotte dire...

ou

> 2. Cervantès fait dire Don Quichotte...

Quelle est la plus littéraire ? la plus stylistiquement belle ?

Comment: faire dire **à**.

Comment: Could this be a dupe? https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16156/358

Comment: You might look up stuff first. If google "faire dire", you will see it's followed by à. And use: site;.fr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux formulations proposées sont grammaticalement incorrectes. La première ne serait pas comprise et la deuxième passerait pour une erreur de frappe.

La construction à utiliser c'est *faire faire quelque chose [à/par](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21801/whether-to-use-par-or-%c3%a0-in-the-make-someone-do-something-construction) quelqu'un*. La seule façon habituelle pour formuler cet exemple est celle-là :

> Cervantès fait dire à Don Quichotte « … »
>   Cervantès fait dire à Don Quichotte que …

Au passage ça donne ça  avec des pronoms :

> Cervantès lui fait dire « … » / que …
>   Cervantès le fait dire à Don Quichotte.
>   Cervantès le lui fait dire.

Comment: "J'ai fait la seule chose que j'ai pue faire." Is this correct or not? Some  French guy keeps telling me I should have written "pu," but that would be incorrect selon les règles de l'accord du participe passé employé avec l'auxiliaire avoir, right?

Comment: Ça n'a rien à voir avec la question et c'est bien « que j'ai pu faire », l'objet de *pouvoir* c'est la proposition infinitive « faire la chose », ce n'est pas la chose elle même. En particulier *pouvoir* n'est pas transitif, le participe passé ne s'accorde donc jamais.